# only parts of pylucene are available?

Tags: pylucene

i'm trying to port some Java Lucene code into pylucene (v 2.3.1).  i'm
using the examples in
http://svn.apache.org/viewcvs.cgi/lucene/pylucene/trunk/samples/, and
most of pylucene seems to come into my python (ubuntu 12.04, pydev
2.6.0, eclipse 3.7.2) enviroment just fine.  eg, i'm able execute
lucene.initVM() (showing JCC is in place) and to define a Porter
stemmer following the example taken from
.../samples/PorterStemmerAnalyzer.py via:

```
self.analyzer = PorterStemmerAnalyzer()
```

but when i try to create a new IndexWriter, it stumbles on the
last argument to its constructor:

```
self.writer = lucene.IndexWriter(self.store, self.analyzer, True, lucene.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED)
```

i get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'IndexWriter' has no attribute 'MaxFieldLength'.
```

this is the error that has me stumped at the moment, but there are
several other hacks (from their version .../samples) i had also made
(but also worry about):

- replace lucene.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT with lucene.LucenePackage
- lucene.SimpleFSDirectory with lucene.MMapDirectory

in order to get this far.

http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/features.html says "The PyLucene API
exposes all Java Lucene classes in a flat namespace in the PyLucene
module."  this doesn't seem entirely right,
lucene.StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET is known to pydev while 
lucene.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET is not.

so it seems i am getting part of/an old version of/...? pylucene
engaged correctly, but not all of it!?  why might this be?

Answer (score 1):

almost certainly the problem had to do with the most recent version of pylucene available as a .deb was 2.3.1 while pylucene is now at v. 3.6.1 !

making from the source distribution takes a bit of touch.  the instructions from JohnW at
http://john.wesorick.com/2011/11/installing-pylucene-on-ubuntu-1110.html were helpful. 
for what it's worth, here are the changes i wound up making, first to the JDK spec for linux2 in `jcc/setup.py`:

```
JDK = {
    'darwin': JAVAHOME,
    'ipod': '/usr/include/gcc',
    'linux2': '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64',
    'sunos5': '/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0',
    'win32': JAVAHOME,
    'mingw32': JAVAHOME,
    'freebsd7': '/usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0'
}
```

and then to the Makefile:

```
PREFIX_PYTHON=/usr
ANT=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 /usr/bin/ant
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/bin/python
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc --shared
NUM_FILES=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I used rikb's answer and it worked, but I had to change

> 'linux2': '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64',

to...

> 'linux2': '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64',

Since I'm using Java 6. It appears he is too, so perhaps he hasn't used that configuration on Linux.

Also note that if you copy and paste all or part rikb's block of stuff for the Makefile you will probably have trailing spaces on each line. Then the 'sudo make' step will fail, rather mysteriously, with a message like "make: execvp: /usr: Permission denied".  This is because the trailing space after "PREFIX_PYTHON=/usr " caused make to try to execute the dir /usr.